# Android: Can I pass the account's credential from Activity to a service class?

Tags: android, android-activity

I created an Activity that make request to Google Calendar, can i send account's credential from actvity to service class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Google credential
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
    ;
    getResultsFromApi();
    startService();
}

public class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

    //com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar createCalendar = null;
    private Exception mLastError = null;
    public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("MyUniversity")
                .build();

        //createCalendar = new com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar();
        //calendar = new com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            if(clear){
                mService.calendars().clear("primary").execute();
               // mService.calendars().delete(calendar.getId()).execute();
                clear = false;
            }
        createEvent();
    }
}
public void startService(){

    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));

}
// Method to stop the service
public void stopService() {
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
}
```

This is the part of activity that uses google account, what i want to do in Service class is control if there are event in current day, i tried to pass credential with intent.putExtras() but doesn't work, i tried also passed credential defining a method to putCredential() and getCredential() in Application class but when i called it in Service class but return a nullpointerexception

Comment: Are you using Intents to start the service? Have you tried setting extras in that? Please show some code with an [edit]

Comment: i tried using intent.putExtras but doesn't work, return me a nullpointerexception

Comment: What threw the exception. That's a lot of code you've posted. Can you try to created a [mcve]?

Comment: @ena: did you get solution for this issue? I'm working on the same.